# JobObjectWrapper: can not instantiate JobObject

Tags: .net, memory-management, jobs

I want to use [JobObjectWrapper](http://jobobjectwrapper.codeplex.com) in my application to limit process memory. I'm trying to instatiate a JobObject with the following code:

```
        JobObject job = new JobObject("Hello");

        ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
        job.CreateProcessSecured(ps);
```

but I'm getting the following exception:

Unhandled Exception: JobManagement.JobException: The management process is runni
ng inside a Job, it will not be able to assign child processes to a new Job.

I'm also getting such exception when I try to run examples in the solution from codeplex(f.e. EndOfProcessMemory).

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using the Visual Studio hosting process?

Comment: By default that option is enabled.. I've also tried disabling it but I have the same result

Comment: Did you try running the sample outside of Visual Studio? (please use the @ tag or I won't see your comments...)

Comment: @Sasha Goldshtein: When I try to run application from windows explorer (i.m. just opening the .exe file) I'm getting the same error. But when I open the application using cmd - it works fine..

Comment: You can use Process Explorer to see whether your Windows Explorer process and Visual Studio process are running inside a job. Right-click them in Process Explorer and if they are inside a job there should be a "Job" tab.